# CSP style src remediation for asp control default inline styling

Tags: inline, content-security-policy

Asp:Image/ treeview renders default inline styling may be framework behaviour, which gives console error for csp. Don't want to use hash/ sha value, unsafe-inline,unsafe-src in csp tag. How to remove this default styling or any way to allow this default styling.Jquery remove attribute doesn't work.

Tried jQuery removeattribute which doesn't work.
Tried to remove style attribute from code behind which doesn't work.